# localhost subdomain wildcard

Tags: 11.10, dns, localhost, hosts, dnsmasq

I'm trying to have `*.localhost` pointing at `127.0.0.1`.

I read this [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1719832) which is quite recent and looks promising but `dnsmasq` can't bind port 53:

```
* Starting DNS forwarder and DHCP server dnsmasq                                                                                                              
 dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Adresse déjà utilisée
```

Does anyone know what's wrong or any other way of achieving? Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/462647/how-can-i-redirect-localhost-to-127-0-0-1-in-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1):

Another program is already using port 53. Maybe dnsmasq is already running or you have another DNS server installed.

What does

```
sudo fuser -v 53/tcp 53/udp
```

print?

Comment: Looks like `dnsmasq` is already running there: 53/tcp:              nobody     1349 F.... dnsmasq and 53/udp:              nobody     1349 F.... dnsmasq. What to do from there?