# How can I redirect *.localhost to 127.0.0.1 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: configuration, dns, dnsmasq

I used to be able to make `foo.localhost`, `bar.localhost`, etc. resolve to 127.0.0.1 by adding

```
address=/localhost/127.0.0.1
```

to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

But `dnsmasq.conf` doesn't exist in Ubuntu 14.04, and just creating it and adding the line doesn't work. Creating `/etc/dnsmasq.d/star-dot-localhost` with the line doesn't work either. So how do I do wildcard DNS redirection in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Do you have `dnsmasq` installed?

Comment: Oh. I thought it was installed by default. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Danatela mentioned, you need to have `dnsmasq` installed in order for that approach to work. You can check if it is installed using `apt-cache policy` command:

```
$ apt-cache policy dnsmasq
dnsmasq:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.68-1
  Version table:
     2.68-1 0
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Use these commands to install it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

Alternatively, you can edit your `/etc/hosts` file and add the following entries:

```
127.0.0.1    foo.localhost
127.0.0.1    bar.localhost
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the same result with "default" sw installed i.e. w/out dnsmasq?

Comment: Is it possible to create a dynamic host like if I enter xyz.localhost or pqr.localhost or etc.localhost then it will open the same?